# Smooth Scrolling for scrollIntoView() function is not working in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, polyfills

I have a button. When clicked upon, I make the page scroll to a div. That's working perfectly in mozilla and IE but its not working properly in chrome browser since its mentioned in nativaly supported. Please suggest what was the issue.

```js
 window.addEventListener('load', function() {

      // scroll into view
      document.querySelector('.js-scroll-into-hello').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.querySelector('.hello').scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
      });

    });
```

```html
<div class="actions">
        <button class="btn js-scroll-into-hello">Scroll into view</button>
      </div>
      <article class="scrollable-parent">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui iure obcaecati, repudiandae aspernatur cumque recusandae
        adipisci consequuntur maiores, quo in nulla ratione facere distinctio beatae, quae consequatur ab labore dolorum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui iure obcaecati, repudiandae aspernatur cumque recusandae
        adipisci consequuntur maiores, quo in nulla ratione facere distinctio beatae, quae consequatur ab labore dolorum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui iure obcaecati, repudiandae aspernatur cumque recusandae
        adipisci consequuntur maiores, quo in nulla ratione facere distinctio beatae, quae consequatur ab labore dolorum.</p> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui iure obcaecati, repudiandae aspernatur cumque recusandae
        adipisci consequuntur maiores, quo in nulla ratione facere distinctio beatae, quae consequatur ab labore dolorum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui iure obcaecati, repudiandae aspernatur cumque recusandae
        adipisci consequuntur maiores, quo in nulla ratione facere distinctio beatae, quae consequatur ab labore dolorum.</p>
        <h3 class="hello"><em>hello!</em></h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui iure obcaecati, repudiandae aspernatur cumque recusandae
        adipisci consequuntur maiores, quo in nulla ratione facere distinctio beatae, quae consequatur ab labore dolorum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui iure obcaecati, repudiandae aspernatur cumque recusandae
        adipisci consequuntur maiores, quo in nulla ratione facere distinctio beatae, quae consequatur ab labore dolorum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui iure obcaecati, repudiandae aspernatur cumque recusandae
        adipisci consequuntur maiores, quo in nulla ratione facere distinctio beatae, quae consequatur ab labore dolorum.</p>
      </article>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you post your code? Cheers

Comment: https://codepen.io/burner/pen/pKpZYP?editors=1000

Comment: What seems to be the problem? For me on Chrome 67.x your snippet seems to be working. One thing you can try is setting the block option also into the scrollIntoView option like so `scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "start"});`.

Comment: @thepio I use chrome 67.x with v8 js, it does have some difference with IE. Chrome moves the div to middle of window and IE move to top. I guess jinfy want the effect on IE?

Comment: @MatrixTai the `block: 'start'` option aligns the scroll to the top of the div also in Chrome doesn't it?

Comment: Thanks guys, now its working fine when i add `block: 'start'`